# How to do multiple actions in unit test - After Insert, After Update, After Delete

Tags: unit-test

I'm trying to write a unit test for my trigger, which operates on After Insert, After Update, After Delete. The trigger works great in real life, but I can't get the unit test to do what I want.

The trigger is designed to count all of the child records and give them a sequence number (in the field Activity_Sequence__c) based on their Scheduled_Date__c field. So, for example, if I insert 20 records, the sequence will be (1 of 20), (2 of 20), (3 of 20), etc...

In my test class, I start by inserting 20 records, and then checking that the sequence worked properly. It does. After that, I try to delete 5 of the records. After I delete the 5 records, the Activity Sequence field should be (1 of 15), (2 of 15), etc..., but is actually still (1 of 20), (2 of 20), etc.. It doesn't update after delete, and I don't understand why.

```
@isTest

private class ActivitySequenceTest {

public static testMethod void ActivitySequenceTest() {

    //Date
    DateTime schedule = System.now();

    //User
    Profile p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];

    User u1 = new User(Alias = 'Holly', Email='holly@testorg.com', 
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Molly', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p1.Id, 
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='Holly#4@testorg.com');
    insert u1;

    //Create a Study Object
    Study__c cStudy = new Study__c();
    cStudy.Name = 'TestStudy';
    insert cStudy;

    //Create a Vendor Object
    Vendor__c vendor = new Vendor__c();
    vendor.Name = 'TestVendor';
    insert vendor;

    List<Activity__c> insertActivities = new List<Activity__c>();

    for(Integer i = 1; i < 21; i++)
    {
        Activity__c v = new Activity__c(Activity__c='Some Text Here',Vendor__c=vendor.Id,Study__c=cStudy.Id, Assigned_to__c=u1.Id, Status__c='Scheduled', Scheduled_Date__c = schedule.date()+i);
        insertActivities.add(v);
    }

    Integer s = insertActivities.size();

    Test.startTest();

    //***TEST 1: INSERT ACTIVITIES***
    insert insertActivities;

    List<Activity__c> assertInsertActivities = [SELECT Id, Activity_Sequence__c, Activity__c, Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c 
                                                    FROM Activity__c 
                                                    WHERE Study__c = :cStudy.Id 
                                                    ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c ASC];

    //test that inserted activities were correctly sequenced
    for(Integer j = 1; j < s; j++)
    {  
       System.assertEquals('('+j+' of '+s+')', assertInsertActivities[j-1].Activity_Sequence__c);    
    }

    //***TEST 2: DELETE ACTIVITIES***
    List<Activity__c> deleteActivities = [SELECT Id, Activity_Sequence__c, Activity__c, Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c 
                                                                FROM Activity__c 
                                                                WHERE Study__c = :cStudy.Id 
                                                                ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c DESC
                                                                LIMIT 5];
    delete deleteActivities;

    List<Activity__c> assertDeletedActivities = [SELECT Id, Study__c, Activity__c, Activity_Sequence__c
                                                            FROM Activity__c
                                                            WHERE Study__c = :cStudy.Id];

    System.debug(assertDeletedActivities.size());

    for(Activity__c x: assertDeletedActivities)
    {
       System.debug(x.Activity_Sequence__c);
    }

    Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should make each case a separate `testMethod`. You can avoid some copy-pasta by abstracting some common setup out into a helper method.

```
static My_Object__c setupRecord()
{
    // common setup
    // do not insert
}

static testMethod void testAfterInsert()
{
    My_Object__c record = setupRecord();
    Test.startTest();
        insert record;
    Test.stopTest();
    // assert stuff
}
static testMethod void testAfterUpdate()
{
    My_Object__c record = setupRecord();
    insert record;
    Test.startTest();
        update record;
    Test.stopTest();
    // assert stuff
}
static testMethod void testAfterDelete()
{
    My_Object__c record = setupRecord();
    insert record;
    Test.startTest();
        delete record;
    Test.stopTest();
    // assert stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I'm rather new at this and your explanation helps.